Output Circuit after LDO
Im trying to understand the chosen values of the components at the RHS of a LDO (AP2112). Here is the circuit: 
I understand that the 100nF capacitor is chosen according to the datasheet to reduce high-frequency ripple and noise while the 22uF capacitor is chosen to ensures the output voltage remains steady, even when there are sudden changes in load (e. g. voltage drops occuring due to some other components connected to the 1V8 power rail). Since the C14 is chosen as per the datasheet, i will ignore it for now. What about L1 and C13? How are their values usually determined; what do their values depend on? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Based on what reference have you placed L1 in the output? do you want to make an low pass filter? why?

Where did the circuit come from? That might give some kind of clue

@MCG It comes from a PCB that interacts with a distance sensor using a MCU

@Andromeda I have not placed anything as im just analyzing what has been done so far

Any inductance in L1's position looks problematic to me.

@Andyaka Why? Isn't L1 forming a low-pass filter together with C13?

As @Andyaka mentioned L1 can introduce a problem to the circuit "The inductor can introduce a voltage drop at higher currents due to its DC resistance (DCR)"

@Tom, I've seen these used before when there are high frequency issues and multiple DC supply rails (usually beads are used, but inductors in the range of value I see here can also be used.) Read "beads demystified" here, appendix B, here, and a discussion here. I'm not experienced enough to go through details. So I'll leave that to you. +1.

@Andromeda it's not just the IR volt-drop but the lack of direct capacitor decoupling on the regulator output can cause instability and noise.

@periblepsis Thank you! I will look into that

@Tom Best wishes. I wish I knew better how to write all this up. I don't. But there may be some good reasoning here. I'm just ignorant, unfortunately. Hopefully, this helps a little, though. Or, perhaps, stimulates a good answer for you!

How L1 value is determined is unknown. We can't know what was in designer's mind. A better question would be, why someone even put L1 there, between LDO and output caps.
